# Touch raises Input/Output error in close with libfuse

Tags: c, linux, gnu, libfuse

I am trying to create an proxy fs with additional permission checking. It will spawn dialog asking user if operation is allowed to be processed.

Sources: https://sourceforge.net/projects/secure-home/

Problem was in touch command. I read in documentation, there is only one way to respond to close request: fuse_reply_err. I set error to 0. When I remove fuse_reply_err(req, 0) line, request was never done. Documentation: https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__lowlevel__ops.html#a1661bb4e3a4e689ff479fdd83b59deff (see at release function's declaration) .
Also, in many example on internet, authors does the same (returning 0 errno).
Problem is with touch command, which will return "Unable to close file: Input/Output error". I look coreutils touch sources: https://github.com/Coreutils/Coreutils/blob/master/src/touch.c . Message was printed, when close return non-zero. I read documentation and close declaration looks that:

```
  int close(int fd)
```

So it returns int and documentation says, it should returns 0 on success. But I do not known, how to return 0 as result from

```
void(* fuse_lowlevel_ops::release) (fuse_req_t req, fuse_ino_t ino, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
```

My code looks that:

```
static void sechome_close(fuse_req_t req, fuse_ino_t ino, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
  struct sh_inode *inode = get_real_inode(ino);

  --inode->ref_count;
  if (0 == inode->ref_count) {
    close(fi->fh);
  }
  fuse_reply_err(req, 0);
}
```

Comment: I also look at:https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/lib/fuse_lowlevel.c . Look at do_release . It calls release callback and if it is not defined, it returns in same manner as I from sechome_close.

Comment: Sorry. That was my bad. I pass function pointer (sechome_close) to bad field of operations struct. Simple type mistake.